# how to create a generic event raising method

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, generics, event-handling

I have a set of events that have the same signature . now I wonder if I can create a generic event handler raising method to do this for all of the events ?

- is this possible to send an event as `<T>` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If this is all within a single class, you can make a method to raise the event which works with any of them.  For example, if your events all were `EventHandler<T>`, you could use:

```
private void RaiseEvent<T>(EventHandler<T> eventHandler, T eventArgs)
{
    if (eventHandler != null)
    {
        eventHandler(this, eventArgs);
    } 
}
```

You could then call this via:

```
this.RaiseEvent(this.MyEvent, new MyEventArgs("Foo"));
```

Comment: with this iplementation , is there any need to put handler in a local variable before checking for null to avoid race condition ?

Comment: @mohsen.d There is no race condition. eventHandler is a parameter.

Comment: @Reed Copsey sorry, but can you explain a bit more ? thank you

Comment: @mohsen.d No - When you pass it in as a parameter, it effectively does the same thing.  `eventHandler` becomes the "local variable" used in the method, so you have no race condition.

Comment: @ReedCopsey : how about when the events are raised from subclasses ? using a generic class is still possible ? I can't find a way to do this .

Comment: @mohsen.d Only the class itself can raise it's events.  You could pass a `Func<EventHandler<T>>` and use a lambda to raise it, but then it gets a bit uglier on the call side.  Often easier to just redo this in the subclass.

Comment: For this code to work, don't forget to add the EventArgs type constraint on your T type: since EventHandler<T> expects T to derive from Event args, you also need to.
`private void RaiseEvent<T>(EventHandler<T> eventHandler, T eventArgs) where T : EventArgs`

Comment: @Vova That's not the case in .NET 4.5 and such- The constraints on EventHandler<T> were removed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

For a static version of Reed Copsey's reply, I created a static class `Event`:

```
public static class Event
{
    public static bool Raise<T>(Object source, EventHandler<T> eventHandler, T eventArgs) where T : EventArgs
    {
        EventHandler<T> handler = eventHandler;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(source, eventArgs);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This also assumes your event handlers are of the type `EventHandler<T>`. The return type was changed from `void` to `bool` and returns whether there were any listeners of the event. Rarely used, so feel free to change back to `void`.

**Example usage:**

```
public event EventHandler<FooArgs> FooHappend;

public void Foo()
{
    Event.Raise(this, FooHappend, new FooArgs("Hello World!");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx2bwtw7.aspx). It describes what you want.

You can create a typed event by using a typed delegate and using that for your event:

```
public delegate void myDel<T>(T stuff);

public event myDel<int> myEvent;

public doStuff()
{
    myDel(1);
}
```

Comment: Not only does that not seem to do what the OP wants, it is not appropriate on SO to *just* post a link, even if it does answer the question.  [more info](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way)